# My iPod touch Gen4 device gives error max open files 78 error and blank screen but emulator runs fine

Tags: ios, file, ipod

I'm posting this in the hopes of saving others a lot of lost time and frustration.

Here is the fix:
In the info.plist file:
Main storyboard file base name        - MainStoryboard_iPhone
Main storyboard file base name (iPad) - MainStoryboard_iPad

My setup was:
Main storyboard file base name (iPhone) - MainStoryboard_iPhone
Main storyboard file base name (iPad)   - MainStoryboard_iPad

This caused the ViewController to never load with no clue in the logs as to what was really going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the info.plist file:
Use
Main storyboard file base name        - MainStoryboard_iPhone
Main storyboard file base name (iPad) - MainStoryboard_iPad

Not this:
Main storyboard file base name (iPhone) - MainStoryboard_iPhone
Main storyboard file base name (iPad)   - MainStoryboard_iPad